# Вычисление интеграла Френеля на промежутке

Tags: matlab

Доброго времени суток! Имеется ли в Matlab встроенная функция для вычисления интеграла Френеля в указанном промежутке? На сайте Matlaba нашел, но не совсем понял как проинтегрировать в определенном промежутке (к примеру, от 0 до z). Стандартные методы типа quad и quadl дают осцилляции из-за особенности интеграла. Хотелось бы избавиться от этих осцилляций.
Может есть какой-то алгоритм для вычисления интеграла?

Answer (score 1):

В matlab есть две встроенные функции: fresnels и fresnelс, которые считаю определенный интеграл от 0 до z для sin и cos соответственно. Их и надо использовать для решения интеграла Френеля.

Comment: Вы можете принять собственный ответ как правильный.